# Setting initial text value on ddlb

Tags: powerbuilder

Is there a such way on PowerBuilder could dynamically set the text value of dropdownlistbox?

I tried 
ddlb_element. Text = 'Fire'  --> but nothing happens.

I have to choose first on the data in ddlb_element before it's having text on ddlb_element

I am new to PowerBuilder, so any idea or something code that would help is much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The DropDownListBox control has the `SelectItem()` method that can take either

- the item position in the list if you know it
- or the string to select (that will be searched in the list), followed by the position to start for search. To search from the top, give it 0

Comment: but nothing happen,

I how can I migrate this vb code to powerbuilder

combo1.text  = 'Fire' --> after loading a form in vb the text value of my combobox is 'Fire'

Comment: This is a weird problem as setting the `.text` property also changes the current selection, as does `.SelectItem()`. Does `.SelectItem()` return `-1`? It will indicate a problem. You should check that the `.text` value is not changed afterwards.

Comment: no, it always return 1, and go to other line (code),

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AddItem to add the value to the drop down first.

li_newitem = ddlb_element.AddItem("Fire")
ddlb_element.SelectItem(li_newitem)

Comment: the return value of li_newitem is 1 ,

Comment: nothing happen, 
I found something weird, I declare li_newitem as a string variable,

but when I use the code li_newitem = ddlb_element_.selectitem(li_newitem) , it says that it is incompatible type in assignement, 

then I used li_newitem = string(ddlb_element_.selectitem) and value for this is only "1", rather that "Fire".. how can this be? 

can someone explain this why? 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the simple example i will give to you. 
 
Just create a window in the powerbuilder. Place a DropDownList Box control on it. Let the name will be same. And then place a button on the same window. paste the following code on the button clicked event. And run the window. Click the button you will get what you want.
Code follows

ddlb_1.additem("FIRE")
ddlb_1.additem("WATER")
ddlb_1.additem("ICE")

ddlb_1.selectitem("FIRE",0)

in this example i used the name to search and value. The value used to mention the starting item of the DDLB. it starts checking from 0.

Another simple code is specifed by Rolan Smith above. I write that too code on simple format for you. Comment the above code and write the following code in the same button clicked event. 
 
Long ll_item
ll_item=ddlb_1.additem("FIRE")
ddlb_1.selectitem(ll_item)

Hope this will help you. 

Regards
Raj~